# The imaginary unit, $i,$ and an alternate representation.

Tags: complex-numbers

Recently, I began working with both complex, and imaginary numbers, and I looked at the complex number $i^{n}.$

If $n = 0, i^{n} = 1,$

$n = 1, i^{n} = i = \sqrt{-1},$

$n = 2, i^{n} = i^{2} = i \cdot i = -1,$

$n = 3, i^{n} = i^{3} = i^{2} \cdot i = -1 \cdot i = -i,$ and

$n = 4, i^{n} = i^{4} = i^{3} \cdot i = -i \cdot i = -i^{2} = -(-1) = 1.$

Would it be correct to say that, $\forall{n}, \Re{\left(i^{n}\right)} = \cos{\left(\frac{n \pi}{2}\right)},$ and $\Im{\left(i^{n}\right)} = \sin{\left(\frac{n \pi}{2}\right)},$ where $\frac{n \pi}{2}$ is in radians?

By this logic, $i^{n} = \cos{\left(\frac{n \pi}{2}\right)} + i \sin{\left(\frac{n \pi}{2}\right)}.$

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: @paw88789 Ah, thank you. The numbers do add up, and it does make sense, but I guess the question that I was asking was whether or not it would be mathematically correct to state $i^{n}$ as the proposed equation.

Comment: I'm not sure if I see the distinction between "correct" and "mathematically correct".  But I would still say, yes, it is mathematically correct.

Comment: @paw88789 Thank you, my friend!

Comment: I just expanded my answer to give another way to see why your guess is correct. It doesn't require Euler's formula or anything similar, just some simple observations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

You can see this using the formula $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$.
First, $i=0+i1=\cos(\pi/2)+i\sin(\pi/2)=e^{i\pi/2}$.
Therefore $i^{n}=e^{in\pi/2}=\cos(n\pi/2)+i\sin(n\pi/2)$.

Let me also give another way to see this, from a different angle.
The function $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb C$ defined by $f(n)=i^n$ has period four since $f(n+4)=i^{4+n}=i^4i^n=1i^n=f(n)$.
The function $g:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb C$, $g(n)=\cos(n\pi/2)+i\sin(n\pi/2)$, is also periodic with period four since the cosine and sine functions have period $2\pi$.
Since $f(n)=g(n)$ for all $n\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ and both functions have period four, they must in fact be equal for all $n\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

You are absolutely correct.
It's a specific aspect of the Euler formula, given that $i = e^{i\pi/2}$ and the Euler formula being : $e^{ix} = \cos x + i  \sin x$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was not aware of the fact that $i = e^{\frac{i \pi}{2}},$ but I was aware of the fact that Euler's identity states that $e^{ix} = \cos{\left(x\right)} + i \sin{\left(x\right)}.$ Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Taylor $i=e^{i \pi/2}$ is what you get from Euler's identity by taking $x=\pi/2$ and simplifying.

Answer (score 3):

By Euler's formula, for any $x=a+bi \in \mathbb{C}$, $$a+bi = re^{i\theta} = r(\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)$$ where $r= \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ and $\theta = \arctan (b/a)$. Thus $i = e^{i\pi/2}$ and $$i^n = e^{ni\pi /2} = \cos\big(\frac{n\pi}{2}\big) + i\sin\big(\frac{n\pi}{2}\big)$$

To see Euler's formula you can think of the complex numbers as ordered pairs $(a,b)$ equipped with a different kind of multiplication: $$(a_1,b_1)\cdot (a_2,b_2) = (a_1a_2,-b_1b_2)$$ Then you can convert these ordered pairs to polar coordinates via the formulas above for $r$ and $\theta$. The expression $re^{i\theta}$ follows from the identities $$\cos x = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2} \hspace{2mm} , \hspace{2mm} \sin x = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$$